CarPlay Mitsubishi outlander connection
Bluetooth stopped syncing my iPhone and screen stopped working. Touch and audio system not functioning to connect phone again. Help
2020 mistibihsi outlander

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the fuses?
